# What is an example of a regular surface whose parametrization of local coordinates is differentiable with exactly continuous inverse?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, submanifold

I am looking for a regular surface such that a point on the surface, the parametrization of local coordinates is differentiable with exactly continuous inverse. For $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^3$ is a differentiable function with exactly continuous inverse, $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f^{-1}(y)=y^{1/3}$. I am looking for something like this for surfaces.

I am using Do Carmo's definition of a regular surface, from *Differential Geometry on Curves and Surfaces*:

DEFINITION $1$. A subset $S \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular surface if, for each $p \in S$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a map $x: U \to V \cap S$ of an open set $U \in R^2$ onto $V \cap S \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

1. $\bf{x}$ is differentiable. This means that if we write
   $\textbf{x}(u, v) = (x(u,v), ~y(u,v), ~z(u,v)), ~(u,v) ∈ U,$ the functions $x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)$ have continuous partial derivatives of all orders in $U$.
2. $\bf{x}$ is a homeomorphism. Since $\bf{x}$ is continuous by condition 1, this means that $\bf{x}$ has an inverse $\textbf{x}^{−1} : V \cap S \to U$ which is continuous.
3. (The regularity condition.) For each q ∈ U, the differential $d\textbf{x}_q: \mathbb{R}^2 → \mathbb{R}^3$ is one-to-one.

Comment: What does "exaxtly continuous" mean"

Comment: Continuous but not differentiable. So $C^0$. e.g. $x^{1/3}$ is the inverse of $x^3$, and it is continuous but not differentiable at 0.

Comment: There is a wide and very useful spectrum between continuous and differentiable (e.g. the Holder spaces). I doubt anyone has ever given $C^0\setminus C^1$ a name.

Comment: But since you only want an example, you can just extend your one dimensional example to be constant along a new dimension

Comment: Okay. I am wondering why Do Carmo defined regular surfaces like this instead of simply saying $x$ is a diffeomorphism, so I assume there is a motivation for it.

Comment: So we can try $z=x^3$, i.e. $\textbf{x}(x,y) = (x, y, x^3)$, but I believe the inverse of the parametrization is simply the (continuous) projection onto the xy-plane. i.e. $\textbf{x}^{-1}(x,y,z) = (x, y)$.

Comment: The point is that we don't yet know what a differentiable function on a surface is, so he can't talk about a diffeomorphism. For your example, try $\mathbf x(u,v) = (u,u^3,v^3)$; of course, the regularity condition (3) will fail, as the inverse function theorem says it must.

Comment: Okay. I can see that the regularity condition fails. If you replace 0 with $e^u$ in your example, then any surface locally parametrized by $\textbf{x}(u,v) = (u^3, v^3, e^u)$ motivates Do Carmo's reason for requiring $\textbf{x}^{-1}$ to be continuous, and not necessarily differentiable. Thank you both for your responses :) .